# Can you give me an example of topological group which is not a Lie group.

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, group-theory, lie-groups, topological-groups

I know the definitions of Lie group and topological group are different. Can you give me an example of topological group which is not a Lie group.

Comment: Another example, which is connected but not locally connected, is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solenoid_(mathematics)

Comment: Does anyone have an example of  a smooth manifold that can be made into a topological group but not a Lie group?

Comment: @IshanBanerjee, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_fifth_problem.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Another example is the rationals under addition with the subspace topology induced from inclusion in $\mathbb R$. Since the rationals are countable, they can't be a manifold of dimension exceeding $0$, so the only possibility would be a $0$ manifold. However, the topology on the rationals is not discrete, so they do not form a $0$-manifold either.

Answer (score 16):

The Cantor set is a topological group. It is homeomorphic to $\{0,1\}^{\omega}$ in the product topology, which is a topological vector space over $\mathbb{Z}_2$. As the set is totally disconnected and not discrete it is easy to see that it cannot be a manifold.

Comment: what topology of {0,1}? discrete ?

Comment: @SamaelManasseh Yes but the product topology is not discrete.

Answer (score 10):

The $p$-adic numbers are a topological group, but not a Lie group.

There are many profinite groups which are not Lie groups, for example the profinite group completion of a knot group.

Comment: (But of course, the $p$-adic numbers provide an example of a $p$-adic Lie group).